# on click once..on click twice ,on click thrice are there any predefined functions in kivy which can do this

Tags: python, button, onclick, kivy

I have got three functions and i would like a button to call it.Is it possible to make a button do function 1 while it is clicked once...perform function 2 while the button is clicked twice and third function on third time when the button is clicked
USING python 3.7 and kivy 1.11

Answer (score 0):

You can use **on_touch_down** *function* and create your own counter for these actions.Start after first touch_down to count clicks and record time together.

For an example,kivy supports **on_double_tap** function. But for thrice i think its only way to do it.You need to set mini click-wait second for keep counting these variables.If user don't click in time or click thrice , you have to set variables to '0'.

Comment: For TextInput , you can find on_double_tap and triple_tap functions already.But there is a no double or triple function for button.